# Sort a column when row input are icons with boolean hidden values - using DataTables plugin

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, datatables

I am using the DataTables plugin for my html table. I can get everything working except the boolean column. This column is composed by icons such as X (value is 0) and ✔ (value is 1).

My script is something like:

```
$('#sorting-table').DataTable({
    paging: false,
    info: false,
    searching: false,
    columnDefs: [
        { orderable: false, targets: 0 },
        { orderable: true, targets: 2 },
        { orderable: true, targets: 3, type: "date-eu" },
        { orderable: false, targets: 4 }
    ],
    order: [[1, 'asc']]
});
```

My column 2 is the one that has icons and bool hidden values and I don't know what to do to make it orderable.

If anyone know the answer I would very much appreciate

Comment: Are you saying you cannot use `orderable: true`? If not, then why not? Does it throw an error? If so, what error? Does it behave incorrectly? If so, in what way? And what is the behavior you want?

Comment: You can provide a [mre], including a sample of the data you are using. So, instead of (or as well as) _describing_ your data "_composed by icons such as X (value is 0)_", you can _show_ us your data. Even better: try to provide us with sufficient code and data so we can recreate the problem for ourselves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can you try this:

```
$.fn.dataTable.ext.order['dom-text-numeric'] = function (settings, col) {
    return this.api()
        .column(col, { order: 'index' })
        .nodes()
        .map(function (td, i) {
            return $('input', td).val() * 1;
        });
};


$('#sorting-table').DataTable({
    paging: false,
    info: false,
    searching: false,
    columnDefs: [
        { orderable: false, targets: 0 },
        { orderable: true, targets: 2, orderDataType: 'dom-text-numeric' },
        { orderable: true, targets: 3, type: "date-eu" },
        { orderable: false, targets: 4 }
    ],
    order: [[1, 'asc']]
});
```

you must change also the 'input' to what html resides in td.

note: i did not do it before.

ref: [datatables examples](https://datatables.net/examples/plug-ins/dom_sort.html)

Comment: I did that and it worked! Changed that 'input' to a span and that was it. Thank you so much for your help